# Expresso Store Inventory Control Panel Layout

Tags: expresso-store, ee2

I'm sure this is some obvious setting that I cannot find, but I've had no luck after consulting the documentation and settings so here goes.

In the Control Panel for Expresso Store 2.0.6, I do not have any options available to edit the products in 'bulk' via the Inventory tab. Several hundred products are listed and paged correctly, but the table doesn't look like this [screenshot from the documentation](https://exp-resso.com/docs/control_panel_inventory.html)  - it's missing the 'plus', sale price and sale price enabled columns, and my price column is a fixed value not a form field.

Any ideas why this might be occurring? I'm using Store 2.0.6 as upgraded from 1.X.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that screenshot is out of date - will get that updated shortly.

In Store 2.0 it is not possible to bulk update prices and quantities like that. In 2.0 we are using EE's built in table libraries to display the order/inventory pages (which is considerably faster), but unfortunately it was not possible to retain the inline row expanders.

The recommended alternative is to update the prices and stock levels on the publish page.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. Not the end of the world, but this bulk edit ability was quite a nice feature to sell to clients. Just to give you some customer feedback, I'm not sure what the benefit of the inventory page is, because if I choose to delete a product (entry) I will always have to navigate to Content > Edit > Products table view anyway.

Comment: You're right, it's really just a quick way to keep tabs on the stock levels of your products. We might be able to restore the bulk price update feature in a future version, but the stock level updating probably won't be making a comeback any time soon unless we can work around the limitations of the new table library.